# How do I rig a tank track mesh?

Tags: mesh, drivers

youtube videos didn't help!
I want the rig to have drivers for location.
[image]

Comment: In cases like this please edit your original question, instead of asking the same thing again.

Comment: I edited the original question but some how its still on hold?